# Application Responsiveness After Being Deactivated : error 5.2.3

Tags: windows-phone-7

I recently submitted a small app working on Silverlight framework. 
But my app got rejected from the marketplace due to error 5.2.3 i.e Application Responsiveness After Being Deactivated. 
What I found was : 
After a user successfully completes the game(a puzzle), I am showing him a dialog :

```
MessageBoxResult mr = MessageBox.Show("You have won! Do you want to start another game?", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
if(mr==MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Now the point is - If the user presses the start button after this dialog box is displayed, the app stops throwing an exception -
  Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground. Error: -2147220990

It seems to me a valid error, though I am not sure how my other apps successfully passed the certification process though they had the same flaw. I have just started developing WP apps so I dont have much knowledge of things to do. Please could you help me a workaround.

Comment: check NavigationService.CanGoBack first.

Comment: @willmel this will not work, when de-activated NavigationService.CanGoBack will still report true.

Comment: @ColinE nevertheless, it should still be checked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is an easy test for this case. It would appear that the `MessageBox` is cancelled before the `Deactivated` event is fired, so there is no way that I can see to test for this state.

My suggestion would be to detect and swallow the specific exception:

```
  MessageBoxResult mr = MessageBox.Show("You have won! Do you want to start another game?", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
  if (mr == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
  {
    try
    {
      NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
      // occurs if message box closed due to de-activation
    }
  }
```

Comment: The app gets tombstombed before this exception. On pressing the back button, I should get back to this state(i.e with the dialog box opened). So how should I handle it?

Comment: Using the MVVM pattern, set a property in your ViewModel to indicate that the MessageBox has been opened. You can learn about when to save your view model state to handle WP7 lifecycle events here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/a-windows-phone-7-1-mango-mvvm-tombstoning-example/